# Website files in GIT - what to do with the images directory?

Tags: git

I'm in the process of moving my company's website from SVN to GIT. It is a large website, with a particularly large assets directory full of images, PDF files, and even a few ISO and exe files (driver downloads, things like that).
While I do want all of this in source control, I'm worried that this huge resources directory (with hundreds of files and nearly 2GB in disk space) could become a problem if it is part of normal GIT activity. For example, if I create a branch or two, will I essentially duplicate this directory? Is there a way to only branch the code but ignore this assets directory?

Comment: Git only stores changes, it does not take snapshots at each commit, so if the asset directory isn't changed all that often the GIT files won't be much get to be massive and unless you change that asset directory in different branches they won't even show up in git. That being said take a look at the [.gitignore documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore). Entries into this file will tell git which files and/or directories to exclude.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm clear, when I create a branch, GIT will not take a snapshot of the master branch, but just start to track changes relative to the master branch? If I have a 2GB master branch, and I set up a development branch and two feature branches, I won't wind up consuming 8GB of storage (unless I make changes that touch every file)?

Comment: You're mostly correct. When you create a branch git will track changes on that branch relative to the commit you branched off of. The commit you branched off of will NOT keep up with the head of the original branch (master in your case) unless you do a `git --rebase` manually. To your second question, you are correct (mostly again) in that it will NOT consume 8GB of storage. Even if you marginally changed every file the repo will still not be that large. I'll see if I can be more exact and give examples in an answer since comments have a small character limit.

Comment: Thanks! that clears up a lot. I can worry a lot less about keeping our assets in GIT.

Comment: "Even if you marginally changed every file the repo will still not be that large." Not sure I agree with this. Git stores the whole file each time you commit a change (unlike Subversion, which just stores the diffs). It can pack (compress) these stored copies though. Your best bet is probably to do a trial conversion and see how big the repository ends up being in practice.

Answer (score 1):

Git doesn't create any more copies of your files then it has to, so you don't need to worry about copying 2GB of images every time you commit or branch, though the initial `clone` is going to take a while. As mentioned in the comments, the best thing to do is convert your repository over and see how it turns out.

If the assets do become a problem, GitHub recently created a [Large File Storage](https://git-lfs.github.com/) extension you can use to easily keep your images files, etc. outside the main repo. Looks like there's only an OSX build right now, but it's open source and hopefully will get some ports soon.